# How to execute udhcpc as non-root

Tags: linux, networking, non-root-user, udhcpc

On a Linux machine, I am trying to run the `udhcpc` command as non-root. I am getting the error `udhcpc: socket: Operation not permitted`. Is there any way to execute `udhcpc` as a simple user in Linux?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Do you really want a non-root user potentially changing the machine's IP address?

Answer (score 1):

A dhcp client needs to bind an ICMP socket, and that requires root permissions¹. You can give a specific user permission to run dhcp through [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). Run `visudo` to add a line like this to the configuration (`joe` is the name of the user to authorize):

```
joe ALL = (root) /sbin/udhcpc
```

¹ 
<sub>Or the appropriate capability, but they're not widespread yet.</sub>